# Criteria API Date field filter based on a single column

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have a requirement in my project where Date filter need to be applied to a pipe delimited field.

How best Criteria API can be used to achieve the same?

```
Table: Flyout

-------------------------------------------------------------
Name                   Date_flyout
-------------------------------------------------------------
John                   |08-06-2017|09-07-2017|02-10-2018|
Adam                   |06-06-2017|10-07-2017|03-06-2018|
Mary                   |07-08-2017|10-06-2017|06-06-2018|
-------------------------------------------------------------

Filter 
From-Flyout-Date: 06-01-2017
To-Flyout-Date  : 07-10-2017

Excepted ResultSet

-------------------------------------------------------------
Name                   Date_flyout
--------------------------------------------------------------
Adam                   |**06-06-2017**|10-07-2017|03-06-2018|
Mary                   |**07-08-2017**|10-06-2017|06-06-2018|
--------------------------------------------------------------


For obvious reason, the below criteria api wont work. However, how best we can modify the below to get excepted results??

criteria.add(Restrictions.ge("Date_flyout", "06-01-2017"))
criteria.add(Restrictions.le("Date_flyout", "07-10-2017"))
```

Comment: why `Date_flyout` has 3 values?

Comment: there is a `Restictions.between()`, but `ge() AND le()` should also work...

Comment: What is your date format ?? is it "mm-dd-yyyy" ??

Answer (score 0):

I think using [.sqlRestriction](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#sqlRestriction) will solve your problem here. Check out the below code :

```
    Session session = ... ;

    Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Flyout.class);
    c.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("substring_index(substring(Date_flyout,2),',',1) between ? and ?",
            new Object[]{"06-01-2017", "07-10-2017"},
            new Type[]{StandardBasicTypes.STRING, StandardBasicTypes.STRING}));
    List<Flyout> tList = c.list();

    for (Flyout f : tList) {

        System.out.println(f.getName() + " - " + f.yourTableProperyDateHere());
    }

    session.close();
```

`substring(Date_flyout,2)` - ignoring the starting pipe from the string 
`substring_index(substring(Date_flyout,2),',',1)` - splitting the text from the first pipe after ignoring the starting pipe

Comment: Thank you!, I will give it a try